# In drupal, Show own unpublished comments

Tags: 7

By default if comment is not approved it is not show to user. In my scenario I want to show own unpublished comment to user in light gray background if comment is not approved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [view_unpublished](https://www.drupal.org/project/view_unpublished%20module) module

> This module allows you to grant access for specific user roles to view unpublished nodes of a specific type. Access control is quite granular in this regard.

After installing the module, navigate to your user access page and assign the appropriate permissions to the roles you wish to be able to view unpublished nodes.

Similar module : [Comment Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/commentaccess)

> Comment Access allows your users to control the comments on their posts. It adds permissions to administer, approve, and delete comments on nodes they create without granting full comment administration access. Permissions are granted by node type, so it's a great way to allow your users to manage comments on their own blogs,